# Enabling Caching for REST requests in Robospice with Jackson and Spring

Tags: android, jackson, robospice

I have an android app using Robospice with Jackson + Spring to perform REST requests. This is working, except that Robospice doesn't seem to be caching the responses. I've also made sure that the cache key is consistent between requests.

I'm setting up the SpiceManager like this:

```
 private SpiceManager mRestManager = new SpiceManager(JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.class);
```

Then, I'm executing the request like this:

```
mRestManager.execute(customSpiceRequest, requestCacheKey, 
            DurationInMillis.ALWAYS, new CustomRequestListener())
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but my customSpiceRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest. I've made certain that requestCacheKey is identical between requests too.

Is there something else I need to do to enable caching between requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, RoboSpice is doing what you are asking for : you pass
DurationInMillis.ALWAYS as a parameter to execute.

This means that the data
in cache will always be considered expired. Thus, the SpiceRequest will
always perform a network call. You should just use a different
cacheDuration value when invoking execute.

Since then, Javadoc has been enhanced :

- cacheExpiryDuration : duration in millisecond after which the content of the cache will be considered to be expired. For instance DurationInMillis.ALWAYS means that data in cache will always be considered expired, thus requests will always perform their network operations to get new data. DurationInMillis.NEVER means data will never be considered as expired, requests will never perform network operations to refresh data but will always return cached data. (see {@link DurationInMillis}).*

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of the current docs "_cacheExpiryDuration - duration in milliseconds after which the content of the cache will be considered to be expired. DurationInMillis.ALWAYS means data in cache is always returned if it exists. DurationInMillis.NEVER means data in cache is never returned.(see DurationInMillis)_" from http://octo-online.github.com/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Hm, How i can specify max cache size?

Comment: There is no such feature on RS. We are open to a PR for this kind of feature.